# Why is there a seeming discrepancy with the expression Cofactor?

Tags: matrix, packages

I was trying to find out the cofactors of a square matrix.

Then I came across the command `Cofactor` in `Combinatorica` package. But it's giving me kind of reversed answer.

An example of what i did:

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
a={{45, 97, 2}, {25, 67, 20}, {36, 30, 37}};
```

Then I did this:

```
Cofactor[a,{1,1}]
```

But the answer it gave didn't seem correct. It gave me an answer 1879, where it should be 590.

So, am I getting this wrong, or is there some issues with this function?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that 1879 is correct.  `Cofactor[a,{1,1}]` is equivalent to `Det[a[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]]]`, which is 1879.

More generally, Cofactor[a,{i,j}] is equivalent to

`Det[Drop[a, {i}, {j}]]*(2*Mod[i*j, 2] - 1)`

The second term here accounts cofactors for the fact that the even positions of odd rows (and the odd positions of even rows) are the negative of the determinant of the residual matrix, after dropping the `{i,j}`-th element.

`Cofactor[a,{3,3}]` is 590.

Comment: The documentation for _Mathematica_ 10 says that the functionality of `Cofactor` is now present in `Det`, but the documentation for `Det` doesn't say how to calculate the cofactor using `Det` and some arguments.